# PHP validation only validating the first text box in my form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, pdo

When i submit my form it executes everything but when i include form validation on other text boxes it wont listen and will just check the usernameTxt text box and that's it.

I have tried using JavaScript but I don't know how to validate with JS but process with PHP.

If anyone can help with either please say!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//Used for stopping users seeing an errors only for our eyes.
//commented out when published
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
include 'includes/dbconnect.php';
session_start();
$error = "";
$username = $_POST['usernameTxt'];
$password = sha1($_POST['passwordTxt']);
$cnfrmPass = sha1($_POST['cnfrmPasswordTxt']);
$email = $_POST['emailTxt'];
$cnfrmEmail = $_POST['cnfrmEmailTxt'];
$fName = $_POST['fNameTxt'];
$lName = $_POST['lNameTxt'];

try{
    if(isset($_POST['submitBn'])){
        if(!empty($username)){
            $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO usersInfo (Username, Password, Email, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :fName, :lName)");
            $query->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $query->bindParam(':password', $password);
            $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $query->bindParam(':fName', $fName);
            $query->bindParam(':lName', $lName);

            if($query->execute()){
                header('Location: signin.php');
            }else{
                $error = "ERROR!";
            }
        }else{
            $error = "Username cannot be empty!";
        }
    }else{
        $error = "<h3>Form cannot be empty!</h3>";
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
<?php
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/header.php';
?>
<div class="wrapper style2" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <article id="work">
        <header>
            <h2>Register Here.</h2>
            <h3><?php  echo $error; ?> </h3>
            <p>If you don't have an account why not <a href="register.php">register</a>?</p>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4u">
                    <section class="box style1">
                        <form name="regForm" action="register.php?attempt" method="post">
                            <label for="username" >Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="usernameTxt" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-     bottom:5px;"/>
                            <label for="password" >Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="passwordTxt" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                            <label for="cnfrmPass" >Password Confirm</label>
                            <input type="password" name="cnfrmPasswordTxt" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                            <label for="email" >Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="emailTxt" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                            <label for="cnfrmEmail" >Confirm Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="cnfrmEmailTxt" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                            <label for="fName" >First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fNameTxt" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                            <label for="lName" >Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lNameTxt"  style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="submitBn" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
                        </form>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
<?php   include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Please do not send a password in plain text, you can find `sha1` and `md5` hash functions in JavaScript online! http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1/

Comment: I haven't sent passwords in plain text have I? I thought i stated it was in sha1 encryption at the top. I.e. '$password = sha1($_POST['passwordTxt']);

Comment: THis code is in your HTML file? If so please provide more relevant coding including the form!

Comment: Give your whole html code

Comment: Code for registration form is below

Comment: Please delete your answer, since it is not an answer. I've updated your code. You can always edit your original question. Please read the faq.

Comment: Okay but i dont see any changes to fixing it? :/

Comment: Nope it's the original question, not going to fix that. See the answer section for answers to your code!

Comment: Btw, you don't send passwords encrypted during your post request. However they will be inserted encrypted into the database +1 for that. Consider salting them too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: I wanted to perform salting previously but i thought if i have a static salt then it poses security issues... Is there anyway to generate a random salt each time a user registers? I was confused with this because if it's randomly generated then when the user logs in will the 'random' salt be the same as when they registered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your PHP script with check lines. The all add up. If a certain number is reached than all fields are correct, if not abort on the field that is incorrect. This can also be done in JavaScript. Will provide you with two solutions.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") //only execute when a post is sent to register.php
{
    $username = $_POST['usernameTxt'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['passwordTxt']);
    $cnfrmPass = sha1($_POST['cnfrmPasswordTxt']);
    $email = $_POST['emailTxt'];
    $cnfrmEmail = $_POST['cnfrmEmailTxt'];
    $fName = $_POST['fNameTxt'];
    $lName = $_POST['lNameTxt'];    

    function validate()
    {
        global $username, $password, $cnfrmPass, $email, $cnfrmEmail;
        var index = 0;
        //start the check
        if (!empty($username) )
        {
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Username can't be empty";
        }
        if ( (!empty($password) && !empty($cnfrmPass) ) && $password === $cnfrmPass)
        {
            index++; //password and confirm password are not empty and equal to each other.
        }
        else
        {
            if (empty($password) || empty($cnfrmPass))
            {
                return "password can't be empty";
            }
            else
            {
                return "passwords do not match";
            }
        }
        if ( (!empty($email) && !empty($cnfrmEmail) ) && $email === $cnfrmEmail) //you also want to check if this is a correct e-mail 
        {
            index++; //email and email password are not empty and equal to each other.
        }
        else
        {
            if (empty($email) || empty($cnfrmEmail))
            {
                return "Email can't be empty";
            }
            else
            {
                return "emails do not match";
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    $validated = validate();
    if (validated == 3)
    {
        //validation pans out --> continue.
        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO usersInfo (Username, Password, Email, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :fName, :lName)");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $query->bindParam(':fName', $fName);
        $query->bindParam(':lName', $lName);

        if($query->execute()){
            header('Location: signin.php');
        }else{
            $error = "ERROR!";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $error = $validated;        
    }
}
```

You can also use HTML5 validation on inputs read up here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

**Solution 2 JavaScript**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function validateForm()
{
    var index = 0;
    function error(obj)
    {
        obj.className = "input_error";
        obj.setAttribute("validate", false);
        document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML += obj.previousElementSibling.innerHTML + " can not be empty.<br/>";
        return false;
    }
    function good(obj)
    {
        index++;
        obj.className = "input_good";
        obj.setAttribute("validate", true);
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML = ""; //empty h3 tag with error info.
    var form = document.getElementsByName("regForm")[0].querySelectorAll("input"); //select all input elements from form
    //iterate them
    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; ++i)
    {
        //use swith to avoid infinite if and elsing
        switch (form[i].type) //check on type.
        {
            //remember all inputs have a label as previousElementSibling
            case 'text' :
                //normal text fields.
                //check if empty and contains normal characters (no !@#$), including all diacritics
                form[i].value.length > 0 ? good(form[i]) : error(form[i]);

            break;
            case 'password' :
                //password fields.
                //check if empty
                form[i].value.length > 0 ? good(form[i]) : error(form[i]);

                if (form[i].name == 'cnfrmPasswordTxt' && form[i].value.length > 0) //if password then check if matches other password
                {
                    if (form[i].value === form[i+1].value)
                    {
                        good(form[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        form[i].className = "input_error";
                        form[i].setAttribute("validate", false);
                        document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML += "Passwords do not match<br/>"; //notify the user that the passwords do not match.
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 'email' :
                //email fields.
                //check if empty
                form[i].value.length > 0 ? good(form[i]) : error(form[i]);

                if (form[i].name == 'cnfrmEmailTxt' && form[i].value.length > 0) //if password then check if matches other password
                {
                    if (form[i].value === form[i+1].value)
                    {
                        good(form[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        form[i].className = "input_error";
                        form[i].setAttribute("validate", false);
                        document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML += "Emails do not match<br/>"; //notify the user that the emails do not match.
                    }
                }
            break;                          
        }
    }

    if (index == 9)
    {
        document.getElementsByName("regForm")[0].submit(); //submit once validated.
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
 </script>
```

Change your submit button

```
<input type="button" name="submitBn" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm()" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;"/>
```

add this css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .input_error {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .input_good {
        border: 1px solid lime;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in the end i decided not to add Javascript, it seemed overkill... I thought maybe just have the server validate it - perhaps it poses less security issues?

Either way here is what i did to fix it:

```
//setting variables to use here
$error = "";
$username = $_POST['usernameTxt'];
$password = sha1($_POST['passwordTxt']);
$cnfrmPass = sha1($_POST['cnfrmPasswordTxt']);
$email = $_POST['emailTxt'];
$cnfrmEmail = $_POST['cnfrmEmailTxt'];

//checking for any empty values or incorrect values
if(empty($username) === true){
    $error = "Username cannot be empty";
}
if($password != $cnfrmPass){
    $error = "Passwords do not match";
}
if($email != $cnfrmEmail){
    $error = "Emails do not match";
}

//if no errors occur start the registration process
if(empty($error) === true){
    $selectQ = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT `Username` FROM `usersInfo` WHERE `Username`=:username");
    //setting the variables to the query
    $selectQ->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $selectQ->execute(); //execute query

    $count = $selectQ->rowCount(); //see if the above query has found anyone
    if($count > 0){
        $error = "User already exists. Please try again.";   
    }else{
        //if no users found start the insert query
        $insertQ = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO usersInfo (Username, Password, Email) VALUES (:username, :password, :email)");
        //setting the variables to the query
        $insertQ->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $insertQ->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $insertQ->bindParam(':email', $email);

        if($insertQ->execute()){
            //if the insert query executed successfully redirect them
            //to the login in page.
            header('Location: signin.php');
        }else{
            //otherwise show this error.
            $error = "Query could not execute!";
        }
    }
}
```